# Facebook sharer don't retrieve images but normal share does

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

When I share an url of my website on Facebook, Facebook retrieve link, url and image.

When I do this with the sharer on my website, the image is never shown

Code of my sharer:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=http://www.kedgebs.com/fr/actualites/sywoc-lequipage-kedge-business-school-champion-du-monde&amp;p[title]=SYWoC : L’équipage KEDGE Business School champion du Monde !', 'Partager', 'width=550,height=300');return false;">Facebook</a>
```

In my page I have:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kedgebs.com/sites/default/files/voile_0.jpg" />
```

Example page :
http://www.kedgebs.com/fr/actualites/sywoc-lequipage-kedge-business-school-champion-du-monde

I have no error in the Facebook debuger and it find the og:image

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide all of those parameters to `sharer.php` if you already have implemented the `og:tags`. The URL is enough. You should try to use something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.kedgebs.com/fr/actualites/sywoc-lequipage-kedge-business-school-champion-du-monde
```

Just provide the URL and let Facebook go out to that link and fetch all the data within the `og:tags` you have placed there.

Comment: perfect thanks, I think all my params had overriden the default og behaviour